# Differentiate reference based on type (problem with argument expansion)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, expansion

Since I use unnumbered sections, I'd like to have a variation of `\autoref` that uses names instead of numbers in the case of sectioning, but keeps its usual behaviour for other environments. I've come up with this naive piece of code, but I don't get it to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring, hyperref, nameref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\KSautoref}[1]{
    \edef\KS@RefType{\expandafter\@fourthoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname}
    \newif\ifKSSectioning\KSSectioningfalse
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{chapter}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{section}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subsection}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subsubsection}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{paragraph}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subparagraph}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}
    \ifKSSectioning\chaptername\nameref{#1}\else\autoref{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test} \label{test}
See \KSautoref{test}.
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.19 See \KSautoref{test}
                         .
?
```

Using `\tracingall` I get this additional information:

```
{\edef}
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@fourthoffive #1#2#3#4#5->#4
#1<-\r@test
```

How can I get `\r@test` to expand as well, so that it's not used as just the first argument?

If there is a package that provides the functionality, I'd rather use that, but still I'd like to know the bit about expansion...

Comment: do you really want `\chapername`? and besides with numbering off, starting with sections,  hyperref will (I think) always use `section*.<number>` so `\nameref` says `section` for things which are not necessarily sections. It is pretty hopeless if things are not numbered to use `\label/\ref`  (or variants).

Comment: I used `\chaptername` as a placeholder for a custom command, but since I didn't get this far with the above code, I never saw the error. Apart from that, I do intend to use this custom command, as `\nameref` just prints the name without the type as `\autoref` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing only one expansion, but you need two. With

```
\expandafter\@fourthoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
```

and `#1=test` as in the example, you get

```
\expandafter\@fourthoffive\csname r@test\endcsname
```

which becomes

```
\@fourthoffive\r@test
```

So you need `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter`.

Here's a better version:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring, hyperref, nameref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifKSSectioning
\newcommand{\KSautoref}[1]{%
  \KSSectioningfalse
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
    \ref{#1}%
  \else
    \protected@edef\KS@RefType{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@fourthoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{chapter}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{section}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subsection}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subsubsection}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{paragraph}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{\KS@RefType}{subparagraph}{\KSSectioningtrue}{}%
    \ifKSSectioning\chaptername~\nameref{#1}\else\autoref{#1}\fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test} \label{test}
See \KSautoref{test}.
\end{document}
```

The added conditional is to cope with the case the reference is not already set; I moved the `\newif` outside the definition, as it's useless constantly creating a new conditional, all it suffices is to set it to false at the beginning of the macro.

I also used `\protected@edef` in case the title contains macros such as `\emph` that don't survive `\edef`.

---

Here's an implementation using `expl3` and regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex, hyperref, nameref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Document level commands
\NewDocumentCommand \KSautoref { m }
 {
  \pazathoth_ks_autoref:n { #1 }
 }

% variables
\tl_new:N \l__pazathoth_type_tl
\regex_const:Nn \c_pazathoth_class_regex
 {
  \A (chapter|section|subsection|subsubsection|paragraph|subparagraph) .*
 }

% internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pazathoth_ks_autoref:n #1
 {
  \cs_if_eq:cNTF { r@#1 } \scan_stop:
   { % if the reference is undefined go to the standard method
    \ref { #1 }
   }
   { % else scan for a named reference
    \__pazathoth_ks_autoref:cn { r@#1 } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pazathoth_ks_autoref:Nn #1 #2
 {
  % get the fourth item in `r@#1`
  \tl_set:Nx \l__pazathoth_type_tl { \tl_item:Vn #1 { 4 } }
  % check if the fourth item starts with a name
  \regex_replace_all:NnNTF \c_pazathoth_class_regex { \1 } \l__pazathoth_type_tl
   { % the replacement was successful; use the section name
    \use:c { \l__pazathoth_type_tl name } \nobreakspace \nameref { #2 }
   }
   { % no name, use \autoref
    \autoref { #2 }
   }
 }

% function variants
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_if_eq:NNTF { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__pazathoth_ks_autoref:Nn { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\providecommand{\sectionname}{Section}

\begin{document}
\section{Test \emph{x}} \label{test}
See \KSautoref{test}.

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item} x
\end{enumerate}

See \KSautoref{item}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see my comment to OP.

Comment: @jfbu It's true that only `chapter` and `section` are distinguished, but it is possible (not easy, I guess) to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I missed a few things there... The crucial point was that on the first run, the reference is not yet set, so `\@fourthoffive` would always fail. Triple `\expandafter` didn't help either, so I discarded it and thought it was a problem with expansion...